# Original array modified even the spread operator

Tags: arrays, operator-keyword, spread

I've been searching for an answer for this for weeks, but I don't understand what am I doing wrong or expecting wrong...

```
let simpleArray = [{"weight": "2kg"},{"weight": "5kg"}];

// I want to turn the weight value string to number without modifying the original array 
function kilosNumber(arrayToSort){

  //Copy to a new array so we don't screw up the original
  const sortedArray = [...arrayToSort];
  //If you dont use spread operator or .slice() trick the next step returns true

  // check that the source is diferent
  console.log(sortedArray === arrayToSort);//false, so its not the same

  //Let's map the array and change the item weight
  sortedArray.map(function(object){
    return object.weight = parseFloat(object.weight);
  });
  return sortedArray;
};

// It returns what I want
console.log(kilosNumber(simpleArray));

// But it modifyes the original
console.log(simpleArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to spread before you use `Array.map()`, because `Array.map()` generates a new array. While mapping, use object spread to generate new objects with the updated value:

```js
const simpleArray = [{"weight": "2kg"},{"weight": "5kg"}];

function kilosNumber(arr) {
  return arr.map(o => ({
    ...o,
    weight: parseFloat(o.weight)
  }));
};

// It returns what I want
console.log(kilosNumber(simpleArray));

// But it modifyes the original
console.log(simpleArray);
```

Comment: But it keeps changing the original.

Comment: No it's not. Run the snippet, and check the results.

Comment: Sorry ^^' 
Thanks a lot, it's been driving me crazy XD

Answer (score 0):

Spread syntax does a shallow copy of your array and hence nested object keys within the object are not cloned, you need to clone them too instead of mutating them. Also when using `map` you need to use the returned value

```js
    let simpleArray = [{"weight": "2kg"},{"weight": "5kg"}];
    
    function kilosNumber(arrayToSort){
     
    
    
      //Let's map the array and change the item weight
      let sortedArray = simpleArray.map(function(object){
        return { ...object, weight: parseFloat(object.weight)};
      });
      return sortedArray;
    };
    
    console.log(kilosNumber(simpleArray));
    console.log(simpleArray);
```

Comment: @OriDrori I just forgot to replace it. I updated the answer

Comment: You need to replace line 8      
`let sortedArray = sortedArray` to `let sortedArray = arrayToSort`
thanks for the answer

Comment: @DanDoW, line 8 is perfectly correct. That is how it should be. You could directly return the result of map, but for the sake on understanding it makes more sense. I just replaced the array being used

Comment: then line 3 `function kilosNumber(arrayToSort){` arrayToSort is not called anywhere
also line 8 needs to delete `let` in order to work

Comment: @DanDoW Its called in the console. `console.log(kilosNumber(simpleArray));` Please run the snippet. It definitely works

Comment: this have no sense

`let simpleArray = [{"weight": "2kg"},{"weight": "5kg"}];
    
    function kilosNumber(arrayToSort){
     
    
    
      //Let's map the array and change the item weight
      let sortedArray = simpleArray.map(function(object){
        return { ...object, weight: parseFloat(object.weight)};
      });
      return sortedArray;
    };
    
    console.log(kilosNumber(simpleArray));
    console.log(simpleArray);`

with this you are not able to use the function with another array

Comment: Ohh dear, If you read about spread syntax you would come to know that it does a shallow copy. Now what we are doing in map function is `making a shallow copy of each individual object inside array and updating the weight field` Also map returns a new array so that is being returned from the function

Comment: Sorry I don't have enoght reputation to chat yet, lets don't worry about this anymore. Please forgive me for the inconveniences

Comment: Unless you worry about what you are writing, you won't realise how to use it. Please read more about Spread syntax here and what they do. Researching and knowing what you are writing is extremely important. More than just solving the problem: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax